# Sharepoint Online provider hosted app as a web part

Tags: azure, sharepoint-online

I have a *Sharepoint Online App* built with `VS 2013 Sharepoint` app template. It is provider hosted in `Azure` due to data connectivity with an onpremise `SQL DB`. It is deployed in company app store in Sharepoint and it appears in the left site navigation. And it works.

But is it possible to get in addable when I pick Edit page in Sharepoint? As in Insert web part? Or is it iframe that is the option?

Answer (score 2):

Could you add a `ClientWebPart`to your Provider Hosted App project and configure it to use the .aspx page you have created?

This would add an "App Part" for your project to be available in SharePoint Webs where your App (Add-In) is installed. This is essentially the iframe route you mentioned, just following MSFT's direction on how to do so. The App Part would then be an option in Edit Mode from the Add a Web Part menu.